# Can I compile Objective-C code to run across multiple platforms?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, dll, cross-compiling

We have a codebase for a sync library written in Objective-C. In general it's only using stuff from the Foundation framework (NSArray's, NSDictionary's, NSURLConnection's etc.).

We also use some Cocoa-specific functionality in this codebase: KVO and delegation.

Is it possible to compile this codebase to other platforms, similar to how it's possible to compile C/C++ code to multiple platforms? How should I go about doing this? What tools would I need?

edit: The platforms we're mostly interested in (if possible of course): Windows, Android, BlackBerry, Windows Phone 7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What platforms do you mean?  Can you list some of the platforms you would like to cross-compile for?

Comment: @PeterM: I've edited my post: Windows, Android, BlackBerry, Windows Phone 7 would be the most important. Afterwards, as many other platforms as possible.

Comment: I'd say that good cross-platform development (like security) has to be considered right from the start, and not really tacked on afterwards.  Its a pity that you didn't write in something like C/C++ right from the start in order to increase your cross platform ability.  Starting with Objective-C is going to be harder for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a delightful article from cocoawithlove - [Options for porting Objective-C/Cocoa apps to Windows](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/04/options-for-porting-objective-ccocoa.html). It atleast answers how to port ObjectiveC to windows.